# Best way to include UIImage in custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to know what is the best and most optimized way to draw UIImage in a custom UITableViewCell that has many elements in it (several images, 2 labels, gradient background). I read that drawRect is the recommended way to go with this since there are several subviews involved and its better to have them all composed as one view content using drawRect. But at the same time I read somewhere else that UIImageView is the preferred way to optimally handle images (caching, fast rendering, etc). I'd appreciate some enlightenment.

Thanks
AF

Comment: I guess in the worst case, you could try both variations and measure performance between both... (Seems like some work, but not tons...)

Comment: It might also depend on the hardware. Personally, I like to test on last gen hw when doing performance tuning.. (i.e. 3GS)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `UIImageView` for its easiness of use. You can drag & drop it in the Interface Builder or just add it programmatically.

Comment: Yes I agree but if you have lots of UIImages in a table cell you will end up having a sluggish scrolling performance. I am trying to optimise the rendering of the cell as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I went to an iPhone Tech Talk once, and a performance engineer said if you're using a `UIImage` in a `UITableView` you should add it with the class method [`UIImage imageNamed:`] to get the most efficient use of the class. Of course you would need to embed that in a `UIImageView`. I usually find any time there are class methods available to make something for you, Apple is very efficient at the way they do it.

Comment: But in other talks they mentioned optimizing custom table cells by using drawRect to compose its elements into one view. So I am confused of what is the best practice and what the drawbacks would be for both approaches.

Comment: I would suggest you post this in the Apple Developer Forums. Apple engineers will often respond to your inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use

`cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"123.jpg"];`